# Snapping in different editors

Tags: snapping

Recently ago, I can activate snappig in Shader Editor and disable it in 3D Viewport. After downloading new version, snapping activate in all editors. I want to activate snapping only in Shader Editor ad disable in other, so how can I do this? May be in settings? I dont want to download old version of Blender.

Comment: I think this was the same in for instance 2.79. Snapping is linked to the scene.

Comment: Okay, may be I am wrong, ut i remember that after updating Blender this snapping confused me, so I think that in 2.83 it was not so

Comment: Same thing in the 2.80 I've here. Shift+tab to quickly toggle it.

Comment: @Lemon is right. In all versions since 2.8 snapping is set for all editors at once. Just tested it :).